# SQL Query to find name from another table in free search

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table containing name of a specific object.
Let's say its columns are as following: id, other_id, name.

Also I have another table which is connected to that previous table with the "other_id", so its columns are: other_id, name.

To find a specific object in a regular search I have used:

```
WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%'"
```

and it is working fine.

However, I want to also search the name of the 2nd table.

**So basically I have two tables, and an id that connects between them, and I want to be able to get the first table rows whose name like "search" or the 2nd table row that is connected to that specific row on the first table, also name is like "search".**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables on the ID that links them. Then you can select any columns you want based on any criteria you specify.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(COL1 INT,
COL2 NVARCHAR(5))

CREATE TABLE #TEST2
(COL1 INT,
COL2 NVARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO #TEST
VALUES ('1', 'BILL'), ('2', 'NANCY')

INSERT INTO #TEST2
VALUES ('1', 'RED'), ('2', 'BLUE')


SELECT A.COL2
      ,B.COL2
FROM #TEST A
JOIN #TEST2 B
ON A.COL1 = B.COL1
WHERE A.COL2 LIKE '%BILL%'
```

This example will select column 2 from both tables where table1.column1 is like '%Bill%'.

Comment: This one worked. I had to give the columns name though so I can differ from eachother names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want results from both tables you can do:

```
SELECT id,other_id,name FROM TABLE1
WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%'
UNION
SELECT null,other_id,name FROM TABLE2
WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%'
```

As you only have other_id,name in your second table, the union will have null as id for the second table's results.

Comment: This isn't what I wanted.

I only wanted the rows from the first table whose name is like search or the name of the 2nd table connected to that row is like search.

Your query gives me all the rows from first and second table that has the name like search.